# How to change a partner license to a regular CRM one?

Tags: licenses, user-management, profile, partner-portal, role-hierarchy

I need to change one of my partner's license type from Partner to a regular CRM one.

This isn't a standard feature, so a manual (data loader + mass update actions will be required)

Has any one done this already?

Any step by step to not forget anything?

Answer (score 3):

The trick to changing the license of a User record is that actually you will be updating the Profile of the user. You may have discovered already that "License" is not actually a field in the user object, even thought it appears in the User record UI.

You would also need to update the Role, as partner users are assigned roles that sit outside of the normal role hierarchy.

So the three pieces of information you'll need is the user's record Id, the Profile Id that you wish to assign to the User.ProfileId field, and the Role Id to assign to the user's RoleId field.

That being said, I have some doubt that this is actually possible. You clearly can't do it in the UI, as you've found. If this is the case, I would suspect that we would also block you from doing this via the API, but give it a try!

Comment: I DO need to change the User License from: Partner --> Salesforce. Not the profile, nor the role

Comment: You cannot change it directly. It must be changed indirectly through the profile assigned to the user. The change in Profile enacts the change of license. That's the only way. So I was giving a more general approach to "what to do to change a user's license". Whether you're allowed to do that from Partner -> Salesforce, I'm not sure.

Comment: The License defines the possibles Profiles a user will have. Not the other way around.

Comment: It looks that way...that's the way we surface in the UI. But trust me, your License Type is determined by reference through your chosen profile. If you look at the data model it goes like this User -> Profile -> User License. There is no direct relationship between User and License. And when you change from a Profile of one license type to another, we always validate that for modifications that are not allowed.

Comment: There are some license type changes we allow in one direction but not another. For instance, if you are a Chatter Free user, we allow your profile to be changed to a Chatter Plus or even Salesforce license. But once you upgrade the license, you can't downgrade back to Chatter Free. And in this instance the "change of license" is always enacted through the assigned Profile.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce does not allow this change of License Type (from a Partner Portal License (e.g. Gold Partner) to Full CRM), at all, not via the API, not via the UI, not via anything. Peter is correct about the *method* of changing a user's License type - it is done indirectly through switching to a Profile associated with a given License type. However, this particular Profile/License 'upgrade' is not allowed by Salesforce - if you try to use the API (e.g. SOQLExplorer) to change the `ProfileId` field of a User record from a Profile associated with a Partner Portal License type to a Profile associated with a Full CRM, license, you get the error message "This change in License types is not allowed":

[image]

And as Peter and Saariko both mentioned, it is not possible via the UI, either:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was:

1. Change the partners data to some mock data
2. Order new regular license
3. Name the new regular license with all the details/values from the partner one
4. Go to the data usage page: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7555/260
5. Using DataLoader: Export all Id's for the relevant objects, and update to the new license ID
6. Done

I think that as this is such a simple process using the DataLoader - Can't see why not to add that as an admin tool ([ideas](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000kd3bAAA))

- The only thing that was left in the Data Usage are 9 leads, that were converted to Accounts. And it seems that Converted leads **can't** be changed.