# How to create a report to see Data/Object usage by User?

Tags: reporting

Is it possible to create a report that will show What/How many objects of each type, are owned by a specific User?

An example will be:

User: John Doe
Account Total 543
Leads: Total 1232
..
..
Custom_Object__c1: Total 221
etc.
etc.

This is NOT shown in the Data Usage page, nor can I find any related report type to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This **IS** shown in the Data Usage page ;)

On every User's page you have something like "Used Data Space   414 KB  [View]". It leads to page:

```
/setup/user/userstorageusage.jsp?id=(User Id)
```

[image]

---

Also - "Setup -> Storage Usage" will have a section on the bottom with "top offenders" in data & file space.